# Configure outgoing email settings SharePoint 2016

Tags: email, incoming-email, 2016, email-enabled-library

I created  a document library and it is having multiple documents and if I select a document and share it then the user should get an email notification that some document is shared with him by `Abc`.

For that should I need to configure Outgoing email settings from server?

Comment: I need do this By using Out of box feature only.

Comment: On server outgoing emails should be configured with a smtp.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send the email from SharePoint, You need an outboundSMTPServer. You can Install SMTP on the SharePoint server or use the exchange server to send the email.

You also need to configure the outgoing email settings in SharePoint( using central admin or powershell.)
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34167.sharepoint-2016-outgoing-email-configuration-settings.aspx